# dataTable the header not matched the body while using scrollY

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am facing issue data Table the header of it not matched the body while using scroll Y: PPHeight .
Any help will be highly appreciated, i have used many solutions but not working for me.trying wrapper width is generated but still issue persist.

**sharing code here **

```
let tblHtmlOverlay = $('#tblHtmlOverlay').DataTable({
dom: "Bfrtip",
bSort: false,
destroy: true,
ServerMethod: "POST",
lengthChange: true,
responsive: false,
deferRender: true,
pageResize: false,
fixedHeader: true,
colReorder: true,
rowReorder: true,
data: A_Data, // We're assuming the Data matches the table construct
paging: false,
scrollY: PPHeight, /// This is resulting in an error. Appears to be a DataTables bug
"scrollX": true, "scrollCollapse": true,
columns: (this.hasHeader === true) ? AtlasPaste.tableHeaders.withheader : AtlasPaste.tableHeaders.thearray
, "language": {
"emptyTable": "Processing your data..."
}
});
```

[image]